# How to troubleshoot Exception thrown when using WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED

Tags: apex, soql, security

I've added the `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` clause to my SOQL queries.  I'm testing them with a user who has a permission set that grants all object permissions (read, create, etc.), and also has read and edit rights to all fields.  I'm getting the `System.QueryException: Insufficient permissions: secure query included inaccessible field` error.  The user in question is a community user, so I've given External Users Public read access to the object as well.  I'm stumped on what could be causing this issue.  How do I troubleshoot, to understand what the clause is complaining about?

UPDATE:

I'm trying out the `SObjectAccessDecision` test recommended below.  For both of the objects included in my query, the results returned by the securityDecision are `null`.

```
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = 
            Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE,
                 [SELECT Id, Name
                    , Logo_Height__c
                    , Logo_Width__c
                    , Logo_URL__c
                    , Import_Font__c
                    , Font_Family__c
                    , Storefront__c
                    , Custom_CSS__c
                    , CC_Account_Group__c
                    , For_Anonymous_Users__c
                    , Use_Header_Logo_in_Footer__c
                    , Footer_Logo_Height__c
                    , Footer_Logo_URL__c
                    , Footer_Logo_Width__c
                    , Header_Logo_Display_Preference__c
                    , Favicon_Url__c
                    , Override_Logo_Size_Unit__c
                    , Footer_Override_Logo_Size_Unit__c
                    , (
                    SELECT Id, Name, Background_Color__c, Text_Color__c, Text_Decoration__c, Text_Font_Weight__c, Link_State__c, Type__c, Text_Size__c, Border__c FROM Quick_Theme_Elements__r
                    WHERE Active__c = TRUE
            )
            FROM Quick_Theme__c
            WHERE Active__c = TRUE
            AND CC_Account_Group__c = :accountGroupId
            AND Storefront__c = :storefront
            //WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED 
            ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC]
                 );

            // Get the removed field names - these are the fields they don't have read access to.
            System.debug(securityDecision.getRemovedFields().get('Quick_Theme__c')); // put sobject here
            System.debug(securityDecision.getRemovedFields().get('Quick_Theme_Element__c')); // put sobject here
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using the [stripInaccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm) method to figure out exactly what field isn't accessible.

Change your query to not use `WITH SECURITY ENFORCED` and pass the query into the stripInaccessible method. You will get a [SObjectAccessDecision](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_SObjectAccessDecision.htm#topic-title) that contains the removed field names. (code below mostly taken from documentation).

```
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = 
         Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE,
                 [SELECT Name, BudgetedCost, ActualCost FROM Campaign]
                 );

// Get the removed field names - these are the fields they don't have read access to.
System.debug(securityDecision.getRemovedFields().get('Campaign')); // put sobject here
```

Edit: In [Summer 20 notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_apex_nc.htm#rn_apex_System_namespace), there's a mention that you can use `stripInaccessible` method to enforce field and object-level security for relationship fields. This seems to imply it didn't work before on relationships (or perhaps was unpredictable) which may explain why it might not have worked for you.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, and I get null back for both of the objects used in the query.  I've updated my answer to show the SOQL I'm using.

Comment: That's interesting. Is the class API 48? I'd also suggest just looping through the results of `.getRecords()` to confirm you're seeing the object with all its fields.

Comment: System.debug('records: ' + securityDecision.getRecords()); does show the parent record being returned, but not the children.  Maybe that's the issue, since I'm doing a related query?

Comment: The documentation specifically mentions it should strip the fields that are inaccessible from the query and subquery so it should work. I'm wondering if it's something special with it being a community user. What happens if you split your subquery into a single query just for debugging purposes (Quick_Theme_Elements__c)? Do you get info on any that are inaccessible?

Comment: I finally got back to this.  I added code that checked the security for the related (or child) records separately.  That works fine.  No fields were removed.  So, I'm guessing WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED does not work with sub-queries.

Comment: For some reason, this problem is no longer a problem.  I'm not sure if I changed something that magically enabled this to work.

Comment: I added an edit as Summer 20 notes have a mention of relationship fields and `stripInaccessible` which seems to suggest it didn't work before? Not sure if it explains the weird behavior you experienced or not.